# Mathematics of Gravity Assists

Tags: trajectory, interplanetary, mission-design, gravity-assist, reference-request

I have some old code for a simple interplanetary trajectory solver and thought it would be interesting to try and extend it to incorporate gravity assists as well. Does anyone know of any books/articles that explain the mathematics behind a simple gravity assist solver so that I can attempt to add it into my mission planner?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to describe what searches you've done, what have you found so far, and why that didn't help you, so potential answerers know what to focus on more precisely? Otherwise this is _answerable_ with a simple web search, say [gravity assist filetype:pdf](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=gravity+assist+filetype:pdf) returns several potentially useful results. Thanks!

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154854/maths-behind-gravity-assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bate's [Fundamentals of Astrodynamics](http://amzn.com/0486600610) is a classic in the field.  There are others, but I would start there.